# Rails enum error handling - 'string' is not a valid 'field'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, enums

Whenever I send a POST request containing a string that isn't allowed, my app breaks with a 500 Internal erorr with the error `'s' is not a valid status`

My model

```
enum status: ['In progress', 'Open', 'Closed']
enum casetype: %w(Info NFI RFC RFA)

validates :status, inclusion: {
  in: Subject.statuses.keys,
  message: 'The only statusses allowed are: "Open", "In progress" and "Closed".' }

validates :casetype, inclusion: {
  in: Subject.casetypes.keys,
  message: 'The only types allowed are: "RFC", "RFA", "NFI" and "Info".' }
```

My controller

```
def create
  @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)

  if @subject.save
    respond_with(@subject, status: :created)
  else
    respond_with(@subject, status: 403)
  end
end
```

Whenever I send a POST request containing no parameters for my status and casetype, the error messages do get raised.

Is it possible to raise an error message, whenever anyone sends a POST request with an invalid string?

Comment: [`You can't validate Rails enums with validates macro`](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13971)